# Update element in Arraylist java

Tags: java, list

Sorry to repeat the question but i am new and looking the others answers didn't help me much.

I'd like to update my arraylist but i get stuck in an error that i cannot solve. Eclipse underlines the word set.
My code is:

```
private List<List> lists;
public void updateList(int index, string a) throws listException {

    for(index = 0; index<list.size(); index++) {
        list.get(index);
        list.set(index, a);
    }
```

Comment: *`but i get stuck in an error that i cannot solve`* What is this error?

Comment: Can you add the error to your question? It's not clear what problem you're running into.

Comment: This does not compile. `String` is upper case, `list` in your `for` loop should be `lists` and what is `List<List>`?

Comment: What is list?  What is restorations?  What does eclipse tell you?

Comment: This code does not compile. What is `list.size()`? You've not defined a `list`. Additionally, where is the error? What exactly is the error?

Comment: Sorry, the error is that i should change the type a to 'list', so it is say to write better public void updateList (int index, list a) throw listException. Is it right?

Comment: It is not at all clear what is supposed to happen here.. Are you trying to set value a at specified index in every list within lists?

Comment: What is `list`?

Answer (score 1):

You named the list as `lists` and trying to access `list` in the `for-loop`.

So your for loop should become like this:

```
for(index = 0; index<lists.size(); index++) {
    lists.get(index);
    lists.set(index, a);
}
```

Also it's `String` and not `string` and you will have to initialize the `list`.

So first change:

```
// Type should be String
private List<String> lists = new ArrayList<>();
```

And am not sure what is `listException`.

```
public void updateList(int index, String a) { 
    // Your rest of the code.
```